# gcc disable -Wall flag for specific files/folders

Tags: android, c++, c, gcc, makefile

I have some open source library files in my project (e.g: http://nothings.org/stb_vorbis/stb_vorbis.c). -Wall option is enabled in my Android.mk file. During compilation several warnings are generated in stb_vorbis.c.

```
warning: unused variable <var>
warning: statement with no effect
warning: <var> defined but not used
warning: <var> may be used uninitialized in this function
```

For some reason I do not want to modify stb_vorbis.c but still want the -Wall option to be available for my own source files. Is there any way to disable -Wall option for specific files/folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using -isystem was the working solution for me.

```
For example, instead of -IC:\\boost_1_52_0, say -isystem C:\\boost_1_52_0.
```

Described in detail in the following thread:

[How do you disable the unused variable warnings coming out of gcc in 3rd party code I do not wish to edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053776/how-do-you-disable-the-unused-variable-warnings-coming-out-of-gcc-in-3rd-party-c)

Thank you [@lee-duhem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004301/lee-duhem) for your kind and useful suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way to disable -Wall option for specific files/folder ?

I do not believe there is any `gcc` option that could be used to achieve this. You need to change your Makefile that you used to compile the problematic source files.

You could do something like

```
CFLAGS:=$(filter-out -Wall, $(CFLAGS))
```

in the Makefile for `stb_vorbis`, if your `make` supports `filter-out` function.

Also you could write a specific rule for that `stb_vorbis.c`:

```
STB_VOBIS_CFLAGS:=$(filter-out -Wall, $(CFLAGS))
stb_vorbis.o: stb_vorbis.c ...
        $(CC) $(STB_VOBIS_CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Comment: I don't get your point. Will it exclude only for stb_vorbis.c or will be applied overall? I have only one make file for all source files.

Comment: @gmuhammad Do you have a Makefile to compile files from `stb_vorbis`? If you have one, put that call to `filter-out` in that Makefile.

Comment: I don't have separate make file for stb_vorbis

Comment: @gmuhammad Then you may need to write specific rule for `stb_vorbis.c`.

Comment: Do you mean to create separate Makefile for stb_vorbis.c and include some rule?

Comment: @gmuhammad No, not separate Makefile. Just add a new rule for `stb_vorbis.c` in your current Makefile.

Comment: using -isystem is also helpful sometimes see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053776/how-do-you-disable-the-unused-variable-warnings-coming-out-of-gcc

Answer (score 2):

Although there's no way to turn off `-Wall` with one option, you *can* turn off specific warnings in GCC, using the `-Wno-*` for warning `*`.  So, for example, to suppress the *unused variable* warning you can add `-Wno-unused-variable`.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html for more information on different warning options.

So for example you could use target-specific variables, like:

```
stb_vorbis.c: CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) you can append the `-w` option to inhibit all warning messages for `stb_vorbis.c` file:

```
stb_vorbis.o: CFLAGS += -w
```

or for an entire directory:

```
third_party/%.o: CFLAGS += -w
```

A general rule of thumb is that if you have two or more mutually exclusive options, gcc will generally take later options over earlier ones.