# gcc warns about unused RAII variable

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, raii, unused-variables

I have a class called `MutexLock`, which does as it sounds : it locks a mutex on construction, and releases it upon destruction:

```
    class OpenEXRMutexLock
    {
#ifndef HAVE_PTHREADS
    public:
        OpenEXRMutexLock() : lock(openEXRmutex) { }
    private:
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock;
#endif
    };
```

When HAVE_PTHREADS is defined, gcc 4.9.1 complains about unused variable whenever I do :

```
OpenEXRMutexLock lock;
```

Of course, the class is meant to be never used outside construction and automatic destruction.

Currently, I did something ugly : I added

```
void OpenEXRMutexLock::dummyFuncAvoidingWarnings() const {}
```

And call it everywhere:

```
OpenEXRMutexLock lock;
lock.dummyFuncAvoidingWarnings(); //Eeerk
```

Is there a way to avoid this **without disabling unused variable warnings on the full project**?

Comment: See [How do you disable the unused variable warnings coming out of gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15053776/1708801) specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23331548/1708801)

Comment: You read my question too fast... I don't want that, because these warnings are interesting

Comment: Please read the specific answer I point to which shows you how to disable it for one variable at a time.

Comment: Please post some actual code, as my g++ 4.9.2 (admittedly not exactly your compiler, but very close) does not give unused variable warnings as soon as a constructor is invoked. Even if that constructor is literally empty. You might also wish to share how you invoke g++ exactly.

Comment: @gha.st : You are right : adding an empty ctor solves the issue. Do you want to enter a detailed answer?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour : my bad, I read your comment too fast... Thanks for the link. I'm not fond of pragmas since they are absolutely not portable, but this works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC is smart enough to detect if the definition of a variable invokes a constructor call. In your case, ensuring that a constructor is indeed invoked (even an empty one) will mark the variable definition as having a side-effect and ensure that you will not get a warning anymore.

[This behavior holds true even for ancient versions of GCC.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17006)

Answer (score 1):

For C++ 17 and beyond, you can use [[[maybe_unused]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused):

```
[[maybe_unused]] OpenEXRMutexLock lock;
```