# C++ Macro causing :"warning: unused variable "LOG__METHOD__" "

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, compiler-flags

I have a macro in my C++ code, macro has an unused variable. I am getting warning for that variable 
the macro is to print the class and method name

```
#define LOG_ENTER(func_name, message)                                      \
    LOG_SET_METHOD(#func_name)                                             \
    LOG_MOD_INTERNAL(TC_TAG(ENTER) << message)
#define LOG_SET_METHOD(name) static const char LOG__METHOD__[] = "::" name "() ";
```

We are using gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC).

> "warning: unused variable "LOG__METHOD__" "

How to suppress this warning? It causing more noise!!

Comment: Show the macro and how you're using it *in your question*. And include the toolchain info. Warning disablement is frequently fickle to the tools being used.

Comment: 3rd answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053776/how-do-you-disable-the-unused-variable-warnings-coming-out-of-gcc may be helpful

Comment: What is the purpose of the unused variable?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of silencing this warning is to use the variable in a dummy expression :

```
int main() {
    int i;
    i;
}
```

However, this triggers "Warning : statement has no effect", because `i` has no side effect and its value is not used. To silence this one, we explicitly ignore the value :

```
int main() {
    int i;
    (void)i;
}
```

And there goes the warning.

Comment: This is a hack (IMHO) and compiler attributes would be a much clearer and cleaner solution (gcc's `__attribute__((unused))`).

Comment: @Otomo well it's [the standard way to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7160837/3233393). And the syntax can't really be mistaken for anything else. No need to resort to compiler magic.

Comment: It is sometimes nice to see that C++ settles such a low threshold about what can be a statement.

Answer (score 0):

A way to disable warning:

```
template <typename T>
void UnusedVar(const T&) {}
```

And then use:

```
UnusedVar(my_var);
```

Casting to `void` is also a common way (but doesn't work for all compiler):

```
(void) my_var; // or static_cast<void>(my_var)
```