# Silencing -Wunused-variable in an if statement

Tags: c++, warnings, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

The following code generates a warning that `temp` is not used (which is true):

```
#include <cstdio>

int f() { return 5; }

int main() {
    if(const int& temp = f()) {
        printf("hello!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that I **NEED** to do this without generating a warning with gcc `-Wall` and clang `-Weverything` (I'm implementing a feature similar to the `SECTION()` stuff of [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#test-cases-and-sections)) .

So any ways to silence it? I tried using `__attribute__((unused))`.

Using `-Wno-unused-variable` globally is not an option for me since I'm writing a header only library.

Comment: duplicated question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053776/how-do-you-disable-the-unused-variable-warnings-coming-out-of-gcc

Comment: `if(const int& temp = 1 ? f() : temp) {` Idk how defined having `temp` there is, but it removes the warning and should be optimized away.

Comment: what about use `(void*)unused_variable;`

Comment: Why do you **NEED** it? And if you do, can you create an example that shows it?

Comment: @juanchopanza the ```SECTION()``` stuff in Catch is implemented that way and I have no idea how to do it any other way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <cstdio>

int f() { return 5; }

int main()
{
  if (const int &temp __attribute__((unused)) = f()) {
    printf("hello!\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This silences the warning for GCC and clang.

Comment: I had used ```__attribute__((unused))``` in the wrong place - before the ```const```

Comment: The [attribute syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax) is not exactly trivial, to say the least, but in my limited experience, as long as you stick to a single declaration, putting it right after the name you defined seems to work (after the parameter list for functions).

Answer (score 2):

If `temp` is unused, in essence it is also probably not needed. Remove it.

```
#include <cstdio>

int f() { return 5; }

int main() {
    if(f()) {
        printf("hello!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I realise this is an MCVE, so why would it need to be there in the first place?

As you mention in the comments, *the destructor of `temp` is important in the target code*. Adding an additional set of braces will add both control of the lifetime of the temporary and ensure its use (hence remove the warning);

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    ~A() { cout << "~A()" << endl; }
    explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
};

A f() { return A{}; }

int main() {
    { // braced to limit scope...
        auto&& a = f(); // can be const A&
        if ( a ) {
            cout << "hello!" << endl;
        }
    } // braced to limit scope....
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33113c2e168a5ddf).

Given the additional constraints of the lifetime of `temp` been extended to the end of an associated `else`, simply forcing the warning to be silenced will work (compiler limited).

```
if (const int &temp __attribute__((unused)) = f())
```

C++11 brings with it the `[[...]]` style of attributes, but the `unused` is [not standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), but clang does support this syntax [`[[gnu::unused]]`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#non-standard-c-11-attributes)

Comment: Well it actually isn't an int but a type with a ctor/dtor and I need the destructor to execute at the end of the if block... maybe I should have given a full example

Comment: @onqtam Its destructor will be executed, even if no named variable here.

Comment: @songyuanyao the lifetime of the temp is different in ```if(myType())``` and ```if(const myType& temp = myType())``` - in the former it will not last until the end of the then block (and the const ref will be)

Comment: Niall - your solution did work but since my macro will expand only to the if statement I cannot force the user to add more braces after the *then* part of the if. also c++98...

Comment: @onqtam. Does the `SECTION()` macro have to run the destructor immediately at the end of the `if()/else`? If not then simply creating a local bind (`const&`) with a random name (possibly add a line number) will run the destructor at the end of whatever the larger scope is.

Answer (score 1):

After jumping through hoops trying to solve this without using `__attribute__((unused))` (which is totally the correct solution), I settled on this.

```
if(const int& temp = ((true) ? f() : (static_cast<void>(temp), f())) )
```

The parenthesis around the `true` suppress a dead code warning, the conditional operator suppresses the warning about use of `temp` before it is assigned, and the cast to `void` removes the unused variable warning.

gcc's `-Wall` and clang's `-Weverything` don't have anything to say, although a reasonable human might.

Fair warning: if `temp` is ever declared `volatile` with a `volatile` copy constructor, this would be UB (some arcane rule about when lvalue to rvalue conversion occurs).