# C Makefile, Compile parts of the project with different rules

Tags: c, makefile

I have a project containing source and header files organized in `N` folders (let's call them `folder1`, `folder2`, ..., `folderN`)

I want to compile `folder1` with `-Wall` but the rest of them with `-w`.
The problem is that the other folders (2 to N) contain only header files which are included in some of the sources in folder1.

When I compile `folder1`, `-Wall` will apply also to the headers in that folder and I do not want that.

This is the makefile I used so far:

```
CC=gcc
LIBS=-iquotefolder2 ... -iquotefoldern

SOURCES=$(wildcard folder1/*.c) $(wildcard folder2/*.c) ... $(wildcard foldern/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

folder1/%.o: folder1/%.c
    $(CC) -Wall $(LIBS) -c -o $@ $^

folder2/%.o: folder2/%.c
    @$(CC) -w $(LIBS) -c -o $@ $^
...

folderN/%.o: folderN/%.c
    @$(CC) -w $(LIBS) -c -o $@ $^

lib.dll: $(OBJECTS)
    @$(CC) -w -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ -o $@ $^

all: lib.dll
```

Is there any way to achieve this? 
I also tried to compile folder2 to folderN in a lib.a and link that library while compiling folder1 but gcc will (obviously) try to include the headers

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html (anybody, feel free to write the info here as an actual answer, if it indeed is solution to OPs problem).

Comment: So you want `folder1/source.c` to be compiled with `-Wall` but `folder2/header.h` included by that file with `-w`?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: please reffer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22708539/6915174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with Makefile. Makefile processes only source files, so you can provide flags in Makefile on source file granularity only. In other words, `gcc` is invoked on source files, and headers are not mentioned in `gcc` invocations.

However, you can instruct `gcc` to adjust warnings in different files:

1. Pass `-isystem <dir>` flag to gcc - this will make `gcc` treat headers located *dir* as system headers. `gcc` by default does not issue any warnings in system headers.
2. Use [`#pragma GCC diagnostic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) to ignore warnings from source files:

Source:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
#include "folder2/bad-header.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: on the other hand `-isystem<dir>` works perfectly for what I need, thanks