# Error 1 error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'rate' and 'hours' in C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to programming. I'm writing a C++ program that a user will their pay rate and the hours worked, and then calculate the pay and hours worked then display it. I finish the program the there are two errors that I tried to fix but I still can't figure out to fix it. The errors and my code is below. Can someone help me and tell me how to fix? I'm using MSVS Express 2013.

Errors:

```
Error   1   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'hours'

Error   2   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'rate'
```

(It is erroring on `displayWeekly(rate, hours);`)

My Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void displayWeekly(double rate, int hours);
double getRate();
int getHours();

int main()
{

double rate; 

int hours;

displayWeekly(rate, hours);

double getRate();
int getHours();

rate = getRate();
hours = getHours();

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void displayWeekly(double rate, int hours)
{
double weekPay;
weekPay = rate * hours;
cout << "Weekly pay is " << weekPay << endl;
}

double getRate()
{
double rate;
cout << "Enter your Hourly rate in the Dollars and Cents = ";
cin >> rate;
return rate;
}

int getHours()
{
int time;
cout << "Please Enter in the Hours you worked" << endl;
cout << "You must Enter a whole Number = ";
cin >> time;
return time;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the value of `hours` to be when you pass it to `displayWeekly`? You didn't initialize it so it has an undefined value.

Comment: Didn't I initialize by inputting in the parenthesis rate and hour, or that not it whats by initializing?

Comment: No. You declare them at the beginning of your main function but give them no value. What do you think the value of hours will be?

Comment: I am referring you to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917424/c4700-uninitialized-local-variable , you need to initialize pointer .

Answer (score 2):

Your new main should look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    double rate;
    int hours;

    //double getRate(); --> where do you think the return value is stored to?
    //int getHours();   --> 

    rate = getRate();
    hours = getHours();

    displayWeekly(rate, hours);  // --> has to go after you put values to rate & hours

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it work just fine. Guess it just the positioning on where I place it.

Answer (score 0):

You pass uninitialized variables to `displayWeekly` ,multiply them and print them which causes the error. Instead,call that function after you call `getHours` and `getRate` so that they get initialized.

Also

```
double getRate(); 
int getHours();
```

In `main` are unecessary.Remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Here the main mistake that you have done is ignoring the order (flow ) of your code .

```
int main()
{

double rate; 

int hours;

displayWeekly(rate, hours);//-> this is the func call that lead to error,cozz the arguments rate,hours are not still initialized .You calculated them after the function call.

double getRate();
int getHours();

rate = getRate();
hours = getHours();
                   //->it helps if you call display func here.
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```