# C4700 Uninitialized Variable, Supposed to get it's value using cin

Tags: c++

Having trouble with a few variables for a tip calculator program. Some of the variables get their value using cin rather than being  declared in the code itself. If I try to put in default values the program won't even look at the input values. So like if I set each to 0, the total amount calculated at the end would be 0.

```
int main()


int numberofDollars;
int numberofQuarters;
int numberofDimes;
int numberofNickles;
int numberofPennies;

string name;
const float dollar = 1.00;
const float quarter = 0.25;
const float dime = 0.10;
const float nickle = 0.05;
const float penny = 0.01;

float valueofDollars = numberofDollars * dollar;
float valueofQuarters = numberofQuarters * quarter;
float valueofDimes = numberofDimes * dime;
float valueofNickles = numberofNickles * nickle;
float valueofPennies = numberofPennies * penny;

double totalDeposit = valueofDollars + valueofQuarters + valueofDimes + valueofNickles + valueofPennies;

cout << "Enter account owner's name: ";
getline(cin, name);
cout << "Enter number of Dollars: ";
cin >> numberofDollars;
cout << "Enter number of Quarters: ";
cin >> numberofQuarters;
cout << "Enter number of Dimes: ";
cin >> numberofDimes;
cout << "Enter number of Nickles: ";
cin >> numberofNickles;
cout << "Enter number of Pennies: ";
cin >> numberofPennies;

cout << "Account Name: " << name << endl;
cout << "Total Deposit = $" << totalDeposit << endl;






system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: Please search before posting a question. There are good chances that you can get an answer much faster just by a quick search. Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26351690/5060335) and you'll get your answer.

Comment: I posted because I could not find my answer in any other questions already asked.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the variables before they are read. You can't declare a *variable* to be some calculation like you have done. You have to calculate the values *after* you have put values into the variables.

When you say

```
float valueofDollars = numberofDollars * dollar;
```

it means "calculate the multiplication of the variable values *at this moment* and store it." It doesn't mean "calculate this every time the variables change." So move all these after the variables have been read.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate values first suing uninitialized values, then read amount of coins **and** not use them after you read them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is, what you wanted to do:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double  numberofDollars, numberofQuarters,
            numberofDimes, numberofNickles,
            numberofPennies;

    string name;

    const double quarter = 0.25, dime = 0.10,
                nickle = 0.05, penny = 0.01;

    double  valueofDollars, valueofQuarters, valueofDimes,
            valueofNickles, valueofPennies, totalDeposit;

    cout << "Enter account owner's name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter number of Dollars: ";
    cin >> numberofDollars;
    cout << "Enter number of Quarters: ";
    cin >> numberofQuarters;
    cout << "Enter number of Dimes: ";
    cin >> numberofDimes;
    cout << "Enter number of Nickles: ";
    cin >> numberofNickles;
    cout << "Enter number of Pennies: ";
    cin >> numberofPennies;

    valueofDollars = numberofDollars;
    valueofQuarters = numberofQuarters * quarter;
    valueofDimes = numberofDimes * dime;
    valueofNickles = numberofNickles * nickle;
    valueofPennies = numberofPennies * penny;

    totalDeposit = valueofDollars + valueofQuarters + valueofDimes + valueofNickles + valueofPennies;

    cout << "Account Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Total Deposit = $" << totalDeposit << endl;

    return 0;
}
```