# C++11-style [[unused]] attribute in gcc?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Under gcc/g++ 4.9 I can write:

```
int x __attribute__((unused)) = f();
```

to indicate that x is intentionally unused.

Is it possible to do this with the C++11 `[[]]` attribute notation somehow?

I tried:

```
int x [[unused]] = f();
```

but it doesn't work.

(Yes, I know it is an implementation-defined attribute.)

Comment: Why would you think it would work? Did you see any language specifications?

Comment: And no it doesn't work. It's gcc extension only. Not language specs

Comment: It does not perfectly fit your question as an answer but [my comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909631/c11-style-unused-attribute-in-gcc#comment51735300_31909665) may interest you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Yes, use `[[gnu::unused]]`**

Like already said `unused` isn't part of the [standard attributes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) specified by the standard.

The standard allows implementation defined attributes too like the `__attribute__` and `__declspec` ones to be used with the new syntax. If a compiler doesn't recognize an attribute (a gcc attribute when compiling on MSVC as example) it'll simply be ignored. (probably with a warning)

For gcc you can use the gnu prefix and the C++11 attribute syntax: `[[gnu::unused]]` instead of `__attribute__((unused))` the same should apply for the other gcc attributes too.

[example without gnu prefix](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ae0e23132c6a413)

[example with gnu prefix](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0c0c8e8dcdd5363)

Comment: Great, with this gcc allows syntax: X x [[gnu::unused]] = y;

Answer (score 28):

There is `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute in C++17. It's implemented in GCC 7, see [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) .

Example from [P0212R1 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0212r1.pdf):

```
[[maybe_unused]] void f([[maybe_unused]] bool thing1,
                        [[maybe_unused]] bool thing2) {
    [[maybe_unused]] bool b = thing1 && thing2;
    assert(b);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The thing you are referring to is known as [attribute specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes). It is an attempt to standardize various, platform dependent, specifiers:

- [`__attribute__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html) in case of **GCC** / **ICC (Linux)**
- [`__declspec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx) on **MSVC** / **ICC (Windows)**

As you can see in attached doc link, the only specifiers supported in C++11 are:

- `[[noreturn]]`
- `[[carries_dependency]]`

and in C++14:

- `[[deprecated]]` (also supported as: `[[deprecated("reason")]]`)

C++ 17 is the version that introduces the required feature:

- `[[maybe_unused]]` ([cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused))

Example from the link:

```
#include <cassert>
 
[[maybe_unused]] void f([[maybe_unused]] bool thing1,
                        [[maybe_unused]] bool thing2)
{
    [[maybe_unused]] bool b = thing1 && thing2;
    assert(b); // in release mode, assert is compiled out, and b is unused
               // no warning because it is declared [[maybe_unused]]
} // parameters thing1 and thing2 are not used, no warning
```

So the answer is: **no, it's not possible, using only C++11 features** - the required C++ version to get this in a portable way is C++ 17.

---

If you are not interested *only* in portable solutions, there might be a way. C++ standard does not limit this list:

> Only the following attributes are defined by the C++ standard. **All other attributes are implementation-specific.**

Various compilers can support some non-standard specifiers. For example, you can read [this page](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#non-standard-c-11-attributes) in order to find out, that Clang supports:

- `[[gnu::unused]]`

Perhaps your version of GCC also supports this specifier. [This page](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53528) contains a bug report referring to generalized attributes support. `[[gnu::unused]]` is also mentioned.

Comment: Ben Deane came up with an interesting C++11 solution which I added as an [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31654792/1708801), it obviously relies on the optimizer but I have not seen one that does not do the right thing yet.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Interesting idea, although I don't think it is a good solution. It may *or may not* be optimized out in such case. `unused` attribute is more explicit and predictable. Also, every known platform has some form of `unused`, so the best *multiplatform* solution would be an `#ifdef` and common macro for all platforms - it's probably the best possible solution (until more attributes will be standardized).

Comment: I would probably file a bug report if it was not properly optimized away, I am not sure I would use that trick but it is worth documenting it may end up very useful to someone else.

Comment: Are there any changes for C++17 (C++1z)?

Comment: The edit queue's full so I can't do anything, but the MSDN link currently redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dabb5z75(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN and should be updated when editing is possible again.