# [[maybe_unused]] on member variable, GCC warns (incorrectly?) that attribute is ignored

Tags: c++, c++17, compiler-warnings, compiler-bug

In the following [example](https://godbolt.org/g/M1ecx2):

```
struct Foo {
    [[maybe_unused]] int member = 1;
    void bar() {
        [[maybe_unused]] int local = 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Foo f{};
    f.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

GCC emits a warning where Clang and MSVC do not:

```
warning: 'maybe_unused' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
     [[maybe_unused]] int member = 1;
```

As far as I can tell, this should be legal (and not ignored by the compiler).  According to the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.unused#2):

> 10.6.7 Maybe unused attribute [dcl.attr.unused]
>   ...
>   2. The attribute may be applied to the declaration of a class, a typedef-name, a variable, **a non-static data member**, a function, an enumeration, or an enumerator.
>   ...

I hate to swing around the "compiler bug" hammer, but I'm not sure what else it could be in this case.

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: What version of `g++` and what exact compilation command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909631/c11-style-unused-attribute-in-gcc

Comment: How would a compiler know whether some public member is unused anyway?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: For local types (function or file scope), compiler might know.

Comment: Did you find a way to remove the warning for gcc, while keeping the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute for your member variables?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Good observation, but this warning appears also for private members

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any attribute can be "ignored by the compiler" for any reason, except where the standard says otherwise (such as using an attribute in a location where it is expressly forbidden).

GCC isn't saying you can't put one there; it's saying that putting one there won't do anything, because they probably don't warn about maybe-unused member variables.

Answer (score 8):

> As far as I can tell, this should be legal (**and not ignored by the compiler**).

Correction:

- *shall* be legal: yes, it may be applied to a declaration of a non-static data member,
- shall not be ignored: no, it's up to the implementation to decide whether or not and how to use this attribute.

Whilst [[dcl.attr.unused]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.attr.unused#2) specified that the `maybe_unused` attribute *may* be applied to a declaration of a non-static data member [**emphasis** mine]:

> The attribute **may be applied to the declaration of** a class, a typedef-name, a variable (including a structured binding declaration), **a non-static data member**, a function, an enumeration, or an enumerator.

there is no strict *requirement* on implementations on *how* to apply this attribute, only a *recommendation* as for how implementations should apply it, as per [[dcl.attr.unused]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.attr.unused#4) [**emphasis** mine]:

> ***Recommended practice:*** For an entity marked maybe_­unused, implementations should not emit a warning that the entity or its structured bindings (if any) are used or unused. For a structured binding declaration not marked `maybe_­unused`, implementations should not emit such a warning unless all of its structured bindings are unused.

This means as long as implementations *allow it* to be applied to a declaration of a non-static data member, they are standard compliant, and it is not a compiler bug that the attribute is non implemented using the *recommended* practice, even if we can argue that a compiler should be able to diagnose an unused non-static data member of a class defined with internal linkage within a single translation unit. E.g. in the following example:

```
// test.cpp
namespace {
struct Foo {
    int member{1};
    void bar() {
        [[maybe_unused]] int local = 0;
    }
};

void bar() {
    Foo f{};
    f.bar();
}
}  // namespace
```

The non-static data member `member` of `Foo` is not used; this is diagnosable and the `maybe_unused` attribute could arguably be used to suppress such an implementation-defined unused warning. However, neither GCC nor Clang warns for the case above, and afaict there are no warnings related to "unused *public* field of local class or class hidden with internal linkage" neither for GCC nor Clang.

Then we may as ourselves why Clang does *not* emit an implementation-defined warning that the attribute will be ignored for the case of non-static data members? The reason is that Clang does emit a [`-Wunused-private-field` warning](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wunused-private-field) for non-used *private* static data members:

```
struct Foo {
    void bar() {
        int local = 0;
    }
private:
    int member{1};
    // Clang: warning: private field 'member' is not used 
};
```

Whereas GCC does not, which would also include why GCC (correctly) warns the `maybe_unused` attribute will be ignored by it for non-static data members (even private ones), as it will simply not diagnose non-used private data members (whereas Clang does). These behaviours are both correct, as it lies in the domain of implementation-defined behaviour.

We may note that there exists a GCC bug report from 2016 that asks for the feature which Clang implements:

- [Bug 72789 - add -Wunused-private-field](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=72789)

which has been

> ... Confirming as an enhancement.

In a duplicate-marked bug report, [*Bug 87409 - Implement -Wunused-private-field*](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87409), Jonathan Wakely comments that *if* this feature were to be implemented in GCC, they would also need to implement the suppression of it for the (maybe) unused attribute:

> Clang suppresses the warning if the member declaration has attribute unused, which we would need to do too.

---

#### Dealing with implementation variance in implementation-defined behaviour

As there are no compiler bugs to hammer down on here, a "portable" (for the specific compilers chosen) implementation of the `Foo` class (if it it were to have, say, (maybe) non-used private data members), w.r.t. unused warnings, would e.g. be to use implementation-specific pragmas, as shown e.g. in [@0x5453: self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65580384/4573247), to attempt to align the implementation-defined behaviours of the selected compilers.

An alternative approach would be to consider entirely removing Clang's `-Wunused-private-field` warning globally (`-Wno-unused-private-field`), leaving these kind of diagnostics to a static analysis tool instead.

Comment: `Whereas GCC does not, which would also include why GCC *(correctly)* warns the maybe_unused attribute will be ignored by it for non-static data members (even private ones), as it will simply not diagnose non-used private data members (whereas Clang does). These behaviours are both correct, as it lies in the domain of implementation-defined behaviour.` It might be correct, but it's very annoying and unnecessary to emit that warning. As developer we are left in a situation impossible to solve neatly.

Comment: @Antonio One upside, however, is that GCC and Clang (in my experience) mutually tries to have similar behaviour in the implementation-defined domain, as can be seen e.g. by the comments in the GCC bug report(s) I link to. On the other hand, implementation-defined "bug" reports (not bugs, per se, but more of feature/change requests) are naturally prioritized lower than actual bug reports, meaning a bug such as the one above is not likely to be implemented unless someone from the open source community jumps in to drive and support with the change.

Comment: ... If I had more time on my hands, it would probably be interesting and instructive to help out sorting out a few GCC/Clang minor bug reports such as this one.

Comment: I am not fully satisfied with this answer, because still my problem is not solved. But I won't do anything to prevent the auto-awarding of the bounty :)

Answer (score 4):

GCC won't warn you for unused member variables in the first place so that attribute has no purpose, that's why it's warning you for ignoring it. It's only a warning, your code is still legal.

Comment: It gets a little interesting when supporting both compilers and when using `-Werror`.  Clang warns on unused members unless `[[maybe_unused]]` is specified, whereas GCC does *not* warn on unused members, but *does* warn if `[[maybe_unused]]` is specified.  So there is no way to leave that variable unused and satisfy both compilers without explicitly disabling the offending warning type on one of the compilers.

Comment: > Clang warns on unused members <

As far as I can tell, it warns only if `struct`/`class` is declared inside an anonymous namespace in a `.cpp` file, or that is a private unused field. E.g.: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WptCHY Is that the case?

Comment: @Youw I've encountered the case described with clang warning for unused private field

Answer (score 4):

Now that I'm looking at this again I'm not able to get Clang to warn about the unused member, so you may be able to remove the attribute to satisfy all compilers.

If you want to disable the warning entirely in GCC, you can use this compile flag:

```
-Wno-attributes
```

And here's an example of selectively disabling the warning, but it's not pretty:

```
struct Foo {
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  pragma GCC diagnostic push
#  pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wattributes"
#endif
    [[maybe_unused]] int member = 1;
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif
    void bar() {
        [[maybe_unused]] int local = 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Foo f{};
    f.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

The `#ifdef __GNUC__`s are required because MSVC emits warnings upon seeing `#pragma GCC`.

Comment: Note that Clang warns for _private_ non-static data members, when diagnosable, and allows using the `maybe_unused` attribute to suppress these warnings.

Comment: I think you are not 100% correct, but you put me on the right path, `-Wno-ignored-attributes` might solve my problem `https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html`. I am posting a separate answer.

Comment: ...And yet, `-Wno-ignored-attributes` in the end doesn't work either, `-Wno-attributes` is the only one that achieve the desired output

Answer (score 1):

**Note, the following, even if apparently correct, doesn't actually work. Only the more extensive option `-Wno-attributes` menage to suppress this warning.**

---

One workaround is to use for gcc the flag [`-Wno-ignored-attributes`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

> `-Wno-ignored-attributes` (C and C++ only)
>
> This option controls warnings when an attribute is ignored. This is different from the `-Wattributes` option in that it warns whenever the compiler decides to drop an attribute, not that the attribute is either unknown, used in a wrong place, etc. This warning is enabled by default.

---

If you are using CMake, this will look like this:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    # using GCC
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-ignored-attributes")
endif ()
```

[Detecting compiler in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055571/2436175)
[Adding compiler flags in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11797272/2436175)