# C++: cleanest practice to write an empty function body

Tags: c++

I want to write a virtual function with an empty body in C++.

These are the ways I know:

---

```
virtual void f(int a, int b, int c) { }
```

If I write like this, the compiler will give a warning about unused parameter. I don't want to globally suppress this kind of warning since it is still useful in other cases.

This question [How do I best silence a warning about unused variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486904/how-do-i-best-silence-a-warning-about-unused-variables) talked about how to suppress unused parameters, but those solutions have shortcomings as described below:

---

```
virtual void f(int a, int b, int c) { (void) a; (void) b; (void) c; }
```

If I write like this, I have to write as many `(void)`'s as the number of parameters. If there are 50 functions and each of them has 10 parameters, I have to manually type 500 `(void)`'s, which is tedious. In addition, each time I add or delete a formal parameter, the corresponding `(void)` statement also needs to be added or deleted. It's a contradiction to the "don't repeat yourself": *two* places have to be modified every time when *one* change happens.

---

```
virtual void f(int /*a*/, int /*b*/, int /*c*/) { }
```

If I write like this, when I write a function call, the IDE will fail to hint the formal parameter's names but just types; and when I override this function in a derived class, the IDE also fails to provide a declaration with the names of these parameters.

---

```
virtual void f(int a, int b, int c) = 0;
```

If I write like this, the derived class has to override this function, which is not what I want.

---

I hope if there were something like this:

```
virtual void f(int a, int b, int c) = default;
```

Is there such a language feature, best practice, or workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: "*I have to manually type 500 `(void)`'s, which is tedious.*" Not if you use regular expression-ish tools to do it for you!

Comment: `-wno-unused-parameter`

Comment: Just suppress the warning in this specific case

Comment: @Cornstalks I don't generate them once but modify them individually and frequently. How can I do this with regular expression?