# Why am I getting a "parameter set but not used" warning when using nullptr_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, warnings, nullptr

I have a custom class implementing `operator==` with `nullptr`.

Here is my code dumbed down into a simple example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class C {
private:
    void *v = nullptr;

public:
    explicit C(void *ptr) : v(ptr) { }

    bool operator==(std::nullptr_t n) const {
        return this->v == n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    uint32_t x = 0;
    C c(&x);
    std::cout << (c == nullptr ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;

    C c2(nullptr);
    std::cout << (c2 == nullptr ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The code works as expected but g++ (version 6.2.1) gives me the following warning:

```
[Timur@Timur-Zenbook misc]$ g++ aaa.cpp -o aaa -Wall -Wextra
aaa.cpp: In member function ‘bool C::operator==(std::nullptr_t) const’:
aaa.cpp:12:36: warning: parameter ‘n’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
     bool operator==(std::nullptr_t n) const {
                                    ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I'm using `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. No warnings with gcc 6.2.1

Comment: @SamVarshavchik try -Wall -Wextra. Reproducible on wandbox's 6.1: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OGeniUkFzE8dRP1v

Comment: Interesting. Note that you can dumb it down even further: `#include <iostream> int main() { std::nullptr_t n = nullptr; if (n == nullptr) std::cout << "yes"; }`

Comment: @wasthishelpful: Perhaps GCC turns out to be correct in generating a warning here, but the wording *"parameter set but not used"* certainly leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Adding `n=n;` to the function makes the warning go away. Looks like the compiler knows that `n` can be `NULL`, and simply optimizes the reference to it away, then ends up producing a warning.

Comment: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on a `nullptr_t` object doesn't access its stored value. Should probably file a bug anyway.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Are you suggesting that this is in fact a bug in `g++`?

Comment: @Venemo: Maybe, if it's supposed to be a different warning or none at all. Or it's a not-yet-supported feature. Or nobody has defined the expected/desired behaviour yet. It's neither right nor wrong because the standard does not mandate a diagnostic message, so whatever a compiler does here is a quality-of-implementation issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really an answer on why this happens, but anyway what value could have `n` but `nullptr`?

Returning `this->v == nullptr` and making the argument unnamed removes the warning:

```
bool operator==(std::nullptr_t) const {
    return this->v == nullptr;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Declaring `n` as an rvalue reference, or as a const lvalue reference also removes the warning:

```
bool operator==(std::nullptr_t&& n) const {
    return this->v == n;
}

bool operator==(const std::nullptr_t& n) const {
    return this->v == n;
}
```

**EDIT2:**

More ways to silence a warning about unused variables can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1486904/1708801) (thx @ShafikYaghmour for pointing it in the comments). The examples above cover the "implicit" ways.

Explicit solutions are available, but IMHO look less coherent since the parameter is effectively used. Tested explicit solutions include:

```
bool operator==(std::nullptr_t n) const {
    (void)n;
    return this->v == n;
}

#define UNUSED(expr) do { (void)(expr); } while (0)

bool operator==(std::nullptr_t n) const {
    UNUSED(n);
    return this->v == n;
}
```

Non portable solution for GCC:

```
bool operator==(__attribute__((unused)) std::nullptr_t n) const {
    return this->v == n;
}
```

Comment: If it's not an answer, then IMO it should be a comment.

Comment: I actually believe this *is* an answer, since it provides a very reasonable way to avoid the warning. Using an identifier for an object of type `std::nullptr_t` is quite pointless.

Comment: I agree, this is a valid answer.

Comment: However, this situatuon may occur in a template where `std::nullptr_t` is actually a type argument.

Comment: I have a question about this answer. In case I remove the parameter name and just compare to `nullptr`: what if somebody casts a non-nullpointer to `nullptr_t`?

Comment: @Venemo I would say that's not possible. Do you have a working example for that?

Comment: @wasthishelpful It's a theoretical question.