# Are there drawbacks to using [[maybe_unused]] for variables used only in asserts?

Tags: c++, attributes, c++17, assert

If a variable is only used in an `assert`, then compilers usually produce a warning when the program is compiled in release mode (i.e. without debug flags). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486904/how-do-i-best-silence-a-warning-about-unused-variables) suggests ways to disable these particular warnings. Among the answers, the C++17 attribute `maybe_unused` is suggested. However, these answers have not really been discussed.

**Are there any drawbacks to using `[[maybe_unused]]` in situations like this one**

```
[[maybe_unused]] const auto i = get_i();
assert(i == 5);
```

in order to silence the warning about `i` being unused in a release build?

Comment: if `get_i` has no side effects, if would probably use `assert(get_i() == 5);`.

Comment: It is the purpose of that attribute.

Comment: I thought there won't be any drawbacks as compiler are free to optimize ```i``` out. No reason not to do so right?

Comment: On the other hand, if `i` is not some trivial type adding `maybe_unused` attribute won't allow compiler to optimize it away, only silence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with such a suggestion is that they might cause some overhead without a warning, especially after some refactoring.

Only the content/expression inside of an assert is usually completely removed in release builds.

If you want to use variables in your assert, you can use lambdas. See this example:

```
#include <cassert>

auto get_i(){
    return 5;
}

int main(){
    /* BAD
    [[maybe_unused]] const auto i = get_i();
    assert(i == 5);
    */
    
    assert([&](){
        const auto i = get_i();
        return i == 5;
    }());
}
```