# Inhibit error messages for unused static functions?

Tags: c, gcc

In C code, if a function is used exclusively within a file, it's good practice to declare it to be `static`.

But sometimes I define a function to be static but don't actually use it (yet), in which case the compiler complains at me:

```
../src/app.c:79:12: error: 'foo' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
```

What's the right way to tell the compiler (gcc in this case) that unused static functions are okay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the `unused` attribute to the function:

```
__attribute__((unused))
static void foo(void)
{
}
```

Comment: This answer has the advantage that you apply it to specific functions rather than a global compiler switch.

Comment: Nice.  This works for variables too, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable that specific error by providing this argument to GCC:

```
-Wno-unused-function
```

The error itself contained a hint that you could do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am lazy and standard compliant, and just do `inline`, and it suppresses the warning.

```
static inline void foo(void)
{
}
```

Comment: Ooh - that's cool.  I would not predict that `inline` would have that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in a function: `(void)unusedFunctionName;` This is how you can suppress unused variables warning for any variables and it is compiler independent (some compiler may still warn, but most probably don't and it doesn't break code for other compilers).

Comment: All true, but the question is about suppressing warning for unused static functions, not unused variables.